# How can I toggle height of <a> where it would work like an accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble setting this up for multiple divs. I have it here http://jsfiddle.net/DpffX/ set up for only one. I would like to have the height of link increase onclick and a hidden div slideDown. When clicking the second link, the first div would slide up then link height back to original height, and second link go through the same opening sequence, so everything works like an accordion. *link tag has a bg image which is a line so it would look like a line is being drawn to the hidden div. Thank you. Updated fiddle jsfiddle.net/J2ySt/2

HTML

```
<div class="slider2">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <a href="#" class="line">link1 |</a>
    <a href="#" class="line">link2 |</a>
    <a href="#" class="line">link3 |</a>
    <a href="#" class="line">link4 |</a>
</div><!-- end .slider2 -->
<div id="link1" style="height:100px; background:#000; color:#fff; margin-left:20px; display:none;">content1</div>
<div id="link2" style="height:100px; background:#000; color:#fff; margin-left:20px; display:none;">content2</div>
<div id="link3" style="height:100px; background:#000; color:#fff; margin-left:20px; display:none;">content3</div>
<div id="link4" style="height:100px; background:#000; color:#fff; margin-left:20px; display:none;">content4</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".line").toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:108},500);
        $("#link1").delay(500).slideDown();
        },function(){
            $(this).delay(500).animate({height:20},500);
            $("#link1").slideUp();
    }); 
});
```

​

Comment: Here's somewhat of a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/DpffX/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `data-*` attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-link="1" class="line">link1 |</a>
<a href="#" data-link="2" class="line">link2 |</a>
<a href="#" data-link="3" class="line">link3 |</a>
<a href="#" data-link="4" class="line">link4 |</a>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".line").toggle(function(){
           var w = $(this).data('link');
           $(this).animate({height:108},500);
           $("#link"+w).delay(500).slideDown();
        },function(){
           var w = $(this).data('link');
           $(this).delay(500).animate({height:20},500);
           $("#link"+w).slideUp();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DpffX/1/)

Comment: Way to be resourceful and not use extra markup.  Great answer, upvote.

Comment: Might I add, I would not have coded this in the way you did, but I've actually learned a better way to do such a feature.  It would not have occurred to me to use a data tag, but rather loops through the elements in Javascript and gather their order which would have been very processor intensive.

Comment: When you click link 1, then link 2, are both supposed to stay down and are both `div`s meant to be displayed?

Comment: This here is what I was looking for:
"Here's somewhat of a solution: jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/DpffX/2 – Andrew Peacock 3 mins ago"

Comment: @cereallarceny yes, `data` tag is very useful and jQuery has made using it much easier.

Comment: Thank you all for taking time to answer.

Comment: @undefined is there a way to only show one at a time? you have the sliding the way I was looking for. I also want to be able to close them completely.

Answer (score 0):

Re-factored the code a little to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".line").click(function() {
        $(".line").animate({height:20},500);
        $("[id^=link]").slideUp();
        $(this).animate({height:108},500);
        $($(this).attr("href")).delay(500).slideDown();
        return false;
    });
});
```

In the HTML you just need to be sure to change the `<a href>` to resemble this: `<a href="#link1">`, with the `href` being the ID of the associated `div` preceded by a `#`. Code seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/DpffX/5/